# Conditional forwarder for subdomain through DNS proxy

Tags: domain-name-system, bind, internal-dns, windows-dns, recursive

I have a Windows AD domain : `contoso.local`
I want to forward all requests to `some.contoso.local` to another DNS server through forwarding DNS server:

`contoso.Local.DNS => Proxy.DNS => some.contoso.local.DNS`

I can not allow direct forwarding from `contoso.Local.DNS => some.contoso.local.DNS` for some reason. `Proxy.DNS` is required.

The `Proxy.DNS` is simple Bind9 machine with config (partial)

```
zone "some.contoso.local" {
  type forward;
  forward only;
  forwarders { 1.2.3.4; }
}
```

On `contoso.Local.DNS` there is NS record saying `some.contoso.local NS ip.of.Proxy.DNS`

Problem:

- When I query `a.some.contoso.local` directly through `Proxy.DNS`, there is all OK.
- When I query `a.some.contoso.local` through `contoso.Local.DNS` there is query fault.

The reason I think is `contoso.Local.DNS` sends query to `Proxy.DNS` with `flags = 0x0000`, and `nslookup` client sets `flags = 0x0100`. This bit means `Allow recursive request`.
[image: dns flags]

Can I somehow override this problem either to

- tell Windows DNS to set `Allow recursive request` bit or to
- make Bind9 ignore this bit is not set
- or anyway else ?

Answer (score 1):

Following the `NS` record is part of recursive resolution -- so at this point it has already been decided that `contoso.local.DNS` is going to be the recursive resolver responsible for the entire query.

So the query being sent out is not the final query, but rather the next step, and the proxy would not be able to know what the client wants. At the same time, forward-only servers do not expect queries with "recursion desired" clear, since all they can do is forward to another (recursive) server, which may or may not be authoritative for the current query -- but queries as part of a recursive lookup always need to be directed at a server that is authoritative.

Since a forward-only server is never authoritative, it needs to reject non-recursive queries, that is what you are seeing -- but altering the flag isn't sufficient.

Comment: And is there ANY way to override it except directly forwarding without any kind of proxy? 
Override this flag on Proxy.DNS or tell contoso.local.DNS to allow forwarding (I can not create ConditionalForwarder on windows DNS for a subzone). Will creating stub zone on Proxy.DNS help me ?

Comment: @filimonic, no. This is not the final query. If you build something tricky to get this query answered, the origin server will disregard the additional records it didn't ask for, and send another query, to another server it is not allowed to talk to.

Answer (score -1):

[Answering myself]
You should create both: NS record and Conditional forwarder.

**First** you create **NS** record for `some.contoso.local` on `contoso.local.DNS` (on windows server: *RightClick on zone name -> New Delegation ...*) and specify the name of `some.contoso.local.DNS` server (the real master of this zone).

This will guarantee that in case of zone transfers of `contoso.local` zone, secondary server will receive information that `some.contoso.local` is hosted by `some.contoso.local.DNS` and will avoid answers like `no such host`.

To avoid validation (If `some.contoso.local.DNS` server is not accessible from `contoso.local.DNS`) you should create this record through PowerShell.

---

At this step, if you're not using proxy, it's finished. Windows DNS will automatically forward to NS specified, but those queries will be non-forwardable.

If you need to forward queries not directly to NS server but through proxy, see next step.

---

**Second** : Only if first step is done, Windows Server DNS MMC Snap-In will allow you creating conditional forwarder for zone `some.contoso.local` to ANY server you want. You write here forwarder `Proxy.DNS` : This will solve problem of  `some.contoso.local.DNS` server is inaccessible from `contoso.local.DNS` server : all queries will be forwarded unmodified this way:

`Client => contoso.Local.DNS => Proxy.DNS => some.contoso.local.DNS`